# Validating userId with XML Schema

Tags: xml, schema

Is it possible to validate the userId inside job_position to match only the values provided in "person" elements using XML Schema?

```
<person id="1">
<firstName>Jo</firstName>
<lastName>Smi</lastName>
</person>
<person id="2">
<firstName>John</firstName>
<lastName>Smith</lastName>
</person> 
<job_position>
  <userId>1</userId> <!-- This is valid -->
  <position>Manager</position>
</job_position>
<job_position>
  <userId>2</userId> <!-- This is valid -->
  <position>Programmer</position>
</job_position>
<job_position>
  <userId>3</userId> <!-- This is Invalid -->
  <position>Systems Analyst</position>
</job_position>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to declare a `key` constraint on the `person` element and a keyref constraint on `userId`.  Both of these need to be declared on the element within which all `person` IDs need to be unique and all `job_position/userId` values need to refer to a person.  Often, that will be the element you expect to serve as the document element.

```
<xs:key name="user-id">
  <xs:selector xpath=".//person"/>
  <xs:field xpath="./@id"/>
</xs:key>
<xs:keyref refer="user-id" name="user-id-ref">
  <xs:selector xpath=".//job_position/userId"/>
  <xs:field xpath="."/>
</xs:keyref>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
<xs:element name="userId">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

For more examples ref: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp